# Prevent Null Queue Message for Azure Webjobs Output Queue

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

According to [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#blobs) WebJobs documentation page, for POCO output queue messages, "A queue message is always created, even if the object is null."

In my scenario, I only want to conditionally output queue messages from my WebJob.  Currently I am getting a ton of null messages to my downstream WebJob using the "out" queue:

```
[Queue("myoutqueue")] out myPOCO outputQueueMessage
```

Is the only way to do this to not use the WebJobs Queue attribute and to queue the message myself using the client library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can conditionally enqueue an output message by using the `ICollector<T>` binding. For example:

`[Queue("myoutqueue")] ICollector<MyPoco> outMessages`

Then, only messages added to the collector via `outMessages.Add(message)` will be sent (one or more). More on `ICollector<T>` and other Queue bindings can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/).

Comment: Thanks.    I should have thought of that.  I have used the ICollector option in another WebJob.  This job was just different because it will always be 0 or 1 message instead of many like my other job.